# How can i Facebook force login in android ,I am using latest facebook sdk?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using the latest Facebook SDK its works fine
But, one problem installing Facebook  then redirect to that Facebook

That's why i can not login forever

I am working old Facebook SDK that have one property like force Auth
Used that is also not worked

i used login for this code
    Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {
        // callback when session changes state
            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            @Override
              public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
                session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(SignUpOptionsActivity.this).setPermissions(Arrays.asList("email")));
//              Log.e("session opened",""+session.isOpened());
                 if (session.isOpened()) {
                    Session.OpenRequest request = new Session.OpenRequest(SignUpOptionsActivity.this);
//                     request.setPermissions(Arrays.asList("email", "publish_actions"));
                   Log.e("open session","open active session");
                    strAccesstoken=session.getAccessToken();
                     List permissions = session.getPermissions();
                    Log.e("current permissions",""+permissions);
                        if (!isSubsetOf(PERMISSIONS, permissions)) {
                          Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session
                                    .NewPermissionsRequest(this, PERMISSIONS);
                        session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
                            return;
                        }

```
              // make request to the /me API
              Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
               // callback after Graph API response with user object
             @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if (user != null) {
                        strFacebookEmail=user.asMap().get("email").toString();
                        Log.e("email","hi"+strFacebookEmail);
                       strFacebookId=user.getId();
                        Log.e("fbid",strFacebookId);
                      strFacebookProfilePic= "http://graph.facebook.com/"+strFacebookId+"/picture?type=large";
                            profilepicture=strFacebookProfilePic.replaceAll(" ","%20").trim();
                     }

                }
              });
            }

    }
    });
```

So please if u have any idea please guide me
Advance thanks for all